# How to explicitly create an optional property in a React component when it is not specificied?

Tags: reactjs

In a React component I need a ref to the HTML element I use for some manual processing (e.g. to listen to resize events). I can do that by defining a ref member in my component and set that in the render method:

```
render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
}
```

However, sometimes the owner of this component also needs this ref for other work (e.g. dynamic handling of certain other events). It makes sense to use the same ref here, so I added a property to the component:

```
render() {
    const { innerRef } = this.props;

    return <div ref={innerRef} />;
}
```

The problem is now that the parent component not always uses the inner ref, so it doesn't specify it when creating the inner component. In order to maintain the functionality of the inner component I want to explicitly create the ref if not given by the parent like:

```
    public constructor(props: MyProps) {
        super(props);

        if (!props.innerRef) {
            props.innerRef = React.createRef<HTMLElement>();
        }

    }
```

However, that's not accepted because `props` is read only. What other approach could I take to accomplish this explicit init, if not provided?

Note: I tried to use the static `defaultProps` to provide such a default, but `defaultProps` is used for all instances of the class, so they all share the same default ref then. Hence this is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to directly assign a new value to props, check if the innerRef is available from the props and if not pass an internally created ref to the div like this.

```
<div ref={innerRef || internallyCreatedRef} />
```

Comment: That would require to check both `innerRef` and `internallyCreatedRef` everytime I need the reference. But in fact I do something similar: I introduced a member variable and assign it like that: `this.containerRef = props.innerRef ?? React.createRef<HTMLElement>();`, which works pretty well. Still, my questions aims for a general way to define a default value for properties.

Comment: Oh okay I missed a part of your question. I'm not exactly sure what's the best practice here. Maybe you could use object destructuring with default values on props?